# jQuery - trigger function is making my page to reload without stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        $("#SuperWebF1").click(function(){
        if ($('[name="shipping_method"]', window.parent.document).is(':checked')){
        event.stopPropagation();
        billing.save();

        parent.jQuery("#LoadingDiv").show().delay(4300).fadeOut();
        parent.jQuery("#OutDiv").hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdiv');
        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdivNoAdress');



        setTimeout(function() {
        if( $('#DisplayMe').length ){
           parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000');
        } else {
           parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000No');
        }
        }, 5100);


        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSS');
        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSSNoAdress');
        parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').addClass('FrameCSS1000');
    }else {
    alert('Моля, изберете начин на доставка!');
    }   

        })

     $('#SuperWebF1').trigger( "click" );

    });

    </script>
```

With this code i'm making the button with id `SuperWebF1` to be clicked at the load of the page.

The problem with the script is that the page is not stopping to reload.

Can i somehow make stop reloading all the time ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. You use global event object - this script will works in IExplorer only, valid handler binding is
$(e).click(function(event){... - it guarantees that u really work with your event


2. Why you call "click" trigger instead of placing click handler in standalone function and call it both from "click" handler and "ready" handler


3. Page cannot reload without reasone, billing.save(); what is this? may be you call submit of form or something like this. Where's no info about "billing.save()" in your example...

Answer (score 0):

Add the type="button" to your button tag

```
    var billing = {save: function(){}};

    $.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var superWebF1 = $("#SuperWebF1");

        superWebF1.click(function(){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        superWebF1.click(function(){
            if ($('[name="shipping_method"]', window.parent.document).is(':checked')){
                console.log("here");
                event.stopPropagation();
                billing.save();

                parent.jQuery("#LoadingDiv").show().delay(4300).fadeOut();
                parent.jQuery("#OutDiv").hide().delay(5000).fadeIn();
                parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdiv');
                parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').removeClass('outerdivNoAdress');



                setTimeout(function() {
                    if( $('#DisplayMe').length ){
                        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000');
                    } else {
                        parent.jQuery('#OutDiv').addClass('OuterDiv1000No');
                    }
                }, 5100);


                parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSS');
                parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').removeClass('FrameCSSNoAdress');
                parent.jQuery('#InnerIframe').addClass('FrameCSS1000');
            }else {
                alert('Моля, изберете начин на доставка!');
            }

        });

        superWebF1.trigger( "click" );

    });

</script>
<form>
    <input name="shipping_method" type="checkbox" checked><button type="button" id="SuperWebF1">Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't get it, What do you mean? Show me please.

Comment: Buttons act like submits for a form:
<form>
    <input name="shipping_method" type="checkbox" checked><button type="button" id="SuperWebF1">Test</button>
</form>

Comment: By adding the type=button you are telling the browser that this is not normal submit button.